# В python 3.{2-7} странно клонируются сложносочиненные субъекты классов

Tags: python-3.x

Итак мы клонируем субъекты класса smthng в список instlst, после чего видим, что список глубины 1 lst1 склонировался как надо в то время как список большей глубины lst2 перезаписывает себя.

При сравнении lst2 из разных субъектов в instlst через is всегда дает False , но lst2 при этом меняется вместе с "предшественниками", хотя по моей логике так быть не должно.

Сердечно прошу объяснить мне как работает эта техномагия, является ли багом, и как мне клонировать списки глубиной 3 внутри класса, так чтоб они сохранялись

P.S deepcopy и @classmethod пробовал, не помогают

```
class smthng:
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.lst1=['a ' for a in range(0,5)]
        self.lst2=[['a ' for a in range(0,5)],['appendix']]#,['a ' for a in range(0,2)]]
        self.mn=5
        self.junk='SomeRandomJunk'
    def cln(self,scnd):
        self.lst1=[]
        self.lst1=self.lst1+scnd.lst1
        self.lst2=[]
        self.lst2=self.lst2+scnd.lst2
        self.mn=scnd.mn
        self.junk=''
        self.junk=self.junk+scnd.junk
        #same for other junk
mninst=smthng()
instlst=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    for u in range(0,3):
        instlst=instlst+[smthng()]
        instlst[len(instlst)-1].cln(mninst)
        instlst[len(instlst)-1].lst1[1]=i
        instlst[len(instlst)-1].lst1[2]=u
        instlst[len(instlst)-1].lst2[0][1]=i
        instlst[len(instlst)-1].lst2[0][2]=u
    print('depth 1 all goes well')
    for u in range(0,len(instlst)):
        print('instlst main is',instlst[u].lst1,'i=',i)
    print('depth 2 previous instances get overwritten')
    for u in range(0,len(instlst)):
        print('instlst main is',instlst[u].lst2,'i=',i) 
    #mninst.cln1(instlst[len(instlst)-1])
```

а вот и вывод на Python 3.7 смотрите сами #Same code, different result

```
depth 1 all goes well
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 0
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 0
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 0
depth 2 previous instances get overwritten
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 0
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 0
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 0
depth 1 all goes well
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
depth 2 previous instances get overwritten
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
depth 1 all goes well
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 2, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 2, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
depth 2 previous instances get overwritten
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
```

Update
В принципе решением данной проблемы является код написанный ниже, но  все еще не понимаю почему при копировании списка глубины 2 способом для глубины 1 при сравнении instlst[a].lst2[b] is instlst[c].lst2[b] при a,c >0 and a,c <len(instlst)-1 and a!=c выдавало False хотя по факту это были ссылки на 1 и тот объект, что меня и запутало.

И еще мне любопытно существует ли реализация этой функции на питоне для произвольной глубины и можно ли как-то менять глубину клонирования в deepcopy потому что у меня оно клонировало правильно лишь до глубины 1 внутри класса на Python 3.{2-7}

P.s ответ на комментарий append вместо сложения списков породит лишние квадратные скобки ; += не использовал во избежании появления еще каких-нибудь глитчей

```
#глубина 1
self.lst1=[]
self.lst1=self.lst1+scnd.lst1
#глубина 2
for i in range(0,len(self.lst2)):
    self.lst2[i]=[]
    self.lst2[i]=self.lst2[i]+scnd.lst2[i]
#глубина 3
for i in range(0,len(self.lst3)):
    for u in range(0,len(self.lst3[i])):    
        self.lst3[i][u]=[]
        self.lst3[i][u]=self.lst3[i][u]+scnd.lst3[i][u]
```

Comment: `append вместо сложения списков породит лишние квадратные скобки`. Я писал, что вместо `instlst=instlst+[smthng()]` нужно использовать `instlst.append(smthng())`. Для случаев, когда нужно сложить два списка используйте не `append`, а `extend`. Например: не `self.lst1=self.lst1+scnd.lst1`, а `self.lst1.extend(scnd.lst1)`. Т.к. `append` добавляет элемент переданный в метод, а `extend` добавляет элементы из коллекции, переданной в метод

Comment: Насчет, deepcopy и объектов. Объекты оно копирует и их поля тоже. И даже если те объекты в списке, то и они будут скопированы. Но заметил интересную вещь, если в списке находятся одинаковые объекты, то будет копия от одного объекта в новом списке, а не копия от каждого объекта.  Пруф добавлю в ответ

Comment: Надоело с вами мурыжить эту задачку :) Применил свои советы к вашему коду и результат правильный. Весь код с результатами в ответе :) Кст, вместо `instlst[len(instlst)-1]` можно использовать `instlst[-1]`, но я бы вообще не использовал индексацию, а работал с самим объектом, что будет добавлен в список (смотрите в моем ответе как)

Answer (score 0):

У вас не происходит копирования списка.

Вы создаете список, складывайте его с другим списком, в результате создается новый список с элементами первого и второго списков.

Заметьте, тут **не будет копирования**, просто **элементы** одного списка **будут перенесены** в другой. А для изменяемых объектов (таких как списки) это означает, что **объект** при таком раскладе **будет в обоих списках одновременно**, т.к. **там нет копирования объекта**, там будет **копия ссылки** на объект.

Суть проблемы:

```
    self.lst1=[]
    self.lst1=self.lst1+scnd.lst1
    self.lst2=[]
    self.lst2=self.lst2+scnd.lst2
```

Наглядный пример:

```
l2 = [['FOO']]
print(id(l2[0]), l2[0])
# 2421659886216 ['FOO']

l1 = []
l1 = l1 + l2
print(id(l1[0]), l1[0])
# 2421659886216 ['FOO']
```

Как тут видно, хоть объект `['FOO']` попал в другой список, он остался тем же объектом. Это видно по его `id`. И если вы, например, в `l1` поменяете список `['FOO']`, то он поменяется в `l2`, т.к. там тоже ссылка на объект.

```
l1[0].append('BAR')
print(l1, l2)
# [['FOO', 'BAR']] [['FOO', 'BAR']]

print(l1[0] is l2[0])
# True
```

#### Решением будет сделать копию списков

- Используйте модуль `copy`, у него есть отличный метод `deepcopy`
- Для добавления в список используйте `append`

Пример:

```
import copy

class smthng:
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.lst1 = ['a ' for _ in range(5)]
        self.lst2 = [
            ['a ' for _ in range(5)],
            ['appendix']
        ]
        self.mn = 5
        self.junk = 'SomeRandomJunk'

    def cln(self, scnd):
        self.lst1 = copy.deepcopy(scnd.lst1)
        self.lst2 = copy.deepcopy(scnd.lst2)
        self.mn = scnd.mn
        self.junk = scnd.junk

mninst = smthng()
instlst = []
for i in range(3):
    for u in range(3):
        obj = smthng()
        obj.cln(mninst)
        obj.lst1[1] = i
        obj.lst1[2] = u
        obj.lst2[0][1] = i
        obj.lst2[0][2] = u

        instlst.append(obj)
        
    print('depth 1 all goes well')
    for x in instlst:
        print('instlst main is', x.lst1, 'i=', i)

    print('depth 2 previous instances get overwritten')
    for x in instlst:
        print('instlst main is', x.lst2, 'i=', i)

    print('\n' + '-' * 100 + '\n')
```

Результат:

```
depth 1 all goes well
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 0
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 0
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 0
depth 2 previous instances get overwritten
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 0, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 0
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 1, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 0
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 0

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

depth 1 all goes well
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 1
depth 2 previous instances get overwritten
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 0, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 1, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 0, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 1, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

depth 1 all goes well
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 2, 0, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 2, 1, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
instlst main is ['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '] i= 2
depth 2 previous instances get overwritten
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 0, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 1, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 0, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 0, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 1, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 1, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 0, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 1, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
instlst main is [['a ', 2, 2, 'a ', 'a '], ['appendix']] i= 2
```

---

**UPD.** `deepcopy` копирует и объекты, и поля в копируемых объектах, даже если те объекты сами находятся в списках:

```
import copy


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Foo[{self.a}, {self.b}, {self.c}, {id(self.c)}, {id(self.c[-1])}]'


foo = Foo()
print(foo)
# Foo[1, 2, [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]], 2432577922504, 2432577922568]

foo2 = copy.deepcopy(foo)
print(foo2)
# Foo[1, 2, [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]], 2432577922376, 2432577922312]

print()

items = [foo, foo, foo]
print(items)
# [Foo[1, 2, [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]], 2432577922504, 2432577922568], Foo[1, 2, [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]], 2432577922504, 2432577922568], Foo[1, 2, [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]], 2432577922504, 2432577922568]]

items2 = copy.deepcopy(items)
print(items2)
# [Foo[1, 2, [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]], 2432577922120, 2432577922056], Foo[1, 2, [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]], 2432577922120, 2432577922056], Foo[1, 2, [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]], 2432577922120, 2432577922056]]
```

Но есть интересная вещь, в списке, имеющий один объект в нескольких элементах (`items = [foo, foo, foo]`) в копии списка будет тоже одна копия объекта, вместо ожидаемых нескольких копий от того объекта.

Это не проблема, если там будут разные объекты, для проверки сделаем разные объекты через копии:

```
items = [copy.deepcopy(foo), copy.deepcopy(foo), copy.deepcopy(foo)]
```

Comment: Deepcopy дает тот же самый результат

Comment: Я специально спрева создавал новый список а потом добавлял к нему(не присваивал) чтобы они были разные и если список глубины 1 то все ок а если глубже

Comment: В целом я понимаю вашу идею, что при глубине больше 1 я складываю пустой список со списком ссылок на объект, которые почему-то при сравнении друг друга через is дают результат False(баг? недоработка? нечто за пределом моего понимания?), но deepcopy делает абсолютно то же.

Comment: @Ptrshllng. еще мне не нравится ваш код с `instlst=instlst+[smthng()]`, тут происходит создание нового списка и переписывание переменной `instlst`, для добавления нового элемента в список используйте `append`, вот так: `instlst.append(smthng())`

Comment: Буду признателен за совет, как мне реализовать описанную задумку не прибегая к рекуррентному вызову процедуры для произвольного количества списков в списках в списке(глубина 3) и желательно без наращивания массива всякий раз при копировании при помощи кучи методов с вызовом через *variables

Comment: @Ptrshllng, знать бы что вы хотите сделать и какого результата добиться :D

Comment: ``` #глубина 1
self.lst1=[]
self.lst1=self.lst1+scnd.lst1
#глубина 2
for i in range(0,len(self.lst2)):
    self.lst2[i]=[]
    #self.lst2[i].append(scnd.lst2[i])
    self.lst2[i]=self.lst2[i]+scnd.lst2[i]
#глубина 3
for i in range(0,len(self.lst3)):
    for u in range(0,len(self.lst3[i])): 
 self.lst3[i][u]=[]
 self.lst3[i][u]=self.lst3[i][u]+scnd.lst3[i][u]```